# Parent Style is not getting applied on Child Style attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have applied the font size in Body of DOM by getting its ID but font-size is not replicated in some child elements.

Moreover I need to know if font-size in elements is applied through external CSS then it can be a problem?

In Code when user click to save the settings then redirectToPreferences() is called and #ulMainMenu, #dropDownMenuItems are the ids of elements at which font-size should be applied

If there is any technical concept that I am mistaken then elaborate

```
function setFontInPreference(data) {
    //data will be font size in % like 100%, 120% etc
    var percentage = data //$("#hdnFontPercentage").val();
    var font = (percentage / 100) * 14;
    var body = document.getElementById('bodywrapper'); //body has Id = bodywrapper
    body.style.fontSize = font + "px";

}

function redirectToPreferences() {

    hideLoader();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/Administration/GetFontSize',
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function () {
            showGridLoader();
        },
        success: function (data) {

            if (data != null && data != 'undefined' && data != '') {

                setFontInPreference(data);
                $("#ulMainMenu").html('');
                $("#dropDownMenuItems").html('');
                $("#dvSubMenu").html('');
                $("#dvQuickLinks").html('');


                getMainMenu();

                //setFont();
            }
            else {



                hideGridLoader();
            }
        },
        complete: function () {
            hideGridLoader();
        },
    });

    ScrollPageToTop();
}


//This is called in Master Script
function setFont() {

    debugger;
    var percentage = $("#hdnFontPercentage").val();
    var font = (percentage / 100) * 14;
    var body = document.getElementById('bodywrapper');

    body.style.fontSize = font + "px";


    })
}
```

Comment: I guess the childs have their own font size so they wont inherit it from body. To check that you can go in Chrome to DevTools (F12), `Elements` Tab, select the element and in the `styles` panel find `computed` styles`

Comment: what is the value of `data` & `font`

Comment: In case child elements have their own font-size, you can enforce you own size by adding "!important" attribute where you are adding font size.

Comment: @brk Data is 100%, 120% etc to define font size

Answer (score 0):

Form controls (ex. input, select, etc) do not automatically inherit font properties. You must have them explicitly inherit them by assigning `font: inherit`.

In the demo below there are two identical forms:

- They both inherit the font properties from `:root` as evident in the `<label>`.
- In the first form `#A` it's form controls still have default font properties.
- In the second form `#B` it has explicitly declared inputs and selects to inherit font properties with `font:inherit`.

So apply `font: inherit` globally and the default font properties to `:root`. As an added bonus having `font-size` defined on `:root` (or `html`) gives you a powerful hook into `font-size` if you use `rem` measure units because that's what they are relative to.

```css
:root {
  font: 700 16px/1.1 Consolas
}

form {
  font-size: 1.5rem
}

#B input, #B select {
  font: inherit
}
```

```html
<form id='A'>
  <label>Test</label>
  <select>
    <option>Test</option>
    <option>Test</option>
  </select>
  <input value='Test'>
  <input type='submit'>
</form>

<form id='B'>
  <label>Test</label>
  <select>
    <option>Test</option>
    <option>Test</option>
  </select>
  <input value='Test'>
  <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add inherit value to the child's property name.

Comment: Thankyou for explanation. I just added inherit property against font-size on every class of the element in Application and it is working !